# Apply Clang's fix-it hints automatically from command line

Tags: c++, clang

Clang (and GCC) compilation errors can come with suggestions on how to fix them: "Fix-it Hints". Does Clang (or maybe another LLVM tool) have an option which would apply these hints? I don't see one in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html. Obviously such a program *could* be written using `-fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits`; that's not what I am asking about.

Comment: On top of asking if we can, we also need to ask if we should. [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) is an **excellent** way of hiding bugs. And we all know we want those as hidden as possible :P

Comment: Why ask "if we should" instead of "is there a possible specific use for it"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

> ```
>  -fix-only-warnings      Apply fix-it advice only for warnings, not errors
>  -fix-what-you-can       Apply fix-it advice even in the presence of unfixable errors
>  -fixit-recompile        Apply fix-it changes and recompile
>  -fixit-to-temporary     Apply fix-it changes to temporary files
>  -fixit=<value>          Apply fix-it advice creating a file with the given suffix
>  -fixit                  Apply fix-it advice to the input source
> ```

Comment: Found it, they need to be passed after `-Xclang`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering, like me, where to find the help given in the accepted answer:

```
clang -cc1 --help | grep -- -fix
```